# How to implement DI pattern in asp.net web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I work with legacy code and try to implement DI pattern in asp.net web service (asmx files) using ninject, but i don`t know where and how to initialize service-locator, that will track dependencies.

Any examples and advices will be usefull, thanks

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378026/ninject-w-asmx-web-service-in-a-mvc3-ninject-3-environment

Comment: I worte an article about web services DI using Unity but maybe you can take some ideas and make it work using NInject: http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/asp-net-web-services-dependency-injection-using-unity/

Comment: @rui-jarimba your article seems to be like exactly what I try to do. Maybe, I can use Unity, instead of Ninject.

Answer (score 0):

There's a ninject module for asp.net webforms. Instructions on setting it up are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130731/1029988).
After that, all you have to do is specify how to resolve you're dependencies and then add an [Inject]able property for each dependency you want injected in you're asmx.cs file

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since I was taken here first by a search engine I thought I would add a pointer to another question with the answer:

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395067/ninject-inject-a-service-interface-in-a-web-service)

The gyst of it is that your web service needs to inherit from Ninject.Web.WebServiceBase instead of System.Web.Services.WebService

Then you can inject into it using the [Inject] annotation.