# MVC4 and the "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." error using Unity to inject dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, visual-studio-2012

I have no idea why Unity is not injecting or something is ignoring the fact that I have parameters in my constructors. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311479/asp-net-mvc-4-ninject-mvc-3-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-ob), but it talks more about NinJect, but leads me to believe maybe there is a similar issue with Unity and Vs2012. I know Unity is working, because in my Application_Start code, after my unity registrations, I resolve an interface from unity and get back all the objects need. I just have no clue why my controller's constructor with parameters is being ignored. I register the controller with unity as well. When I try to hit that controller I get the `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` error.

I am curious if anyone else has run into this same issue.

Comment: What sort of 'controller' are you talking about? Is that an `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` or a `System.Web.Http.ApiController`? And what is your current registration? How do you register your `IDependencyResolver`?

Comment: without any code, seems difficult to help you...

Comment: @Steven, your question about how I was registering the IDependencyResolver made me think, because I had to use the IDependencyScope when registering my resolver with the ApiController. I am using  a the standard Controller. So, registering it with the SetResolver() worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to give props to [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven), since he steered me in the right direction, but basically, I was using a method to register my resolver with the [ApiController](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver) rather than using the SetResolver method to register it with a standard controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had installed Unity and then Unity.Mvc4.  I uninstalled everything to do with Unity and reinstalled only Unity.Mvc4 and everything worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

For this error in Unity go to the Global.asax and write the following code.
Initialise the Bootstrapper.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();





    }
```