# Ninject not working in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a simple MVC 4 Application:

I installed Ninject MVC 3 from nuget and I register the services into `NinjectWebCommon.cs` from `App_Start folder`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IAppFormAppUnitOfWork>()
          .To<AppFormAppUnitOfWork>()
          .InRequestScope();
}
```

I have a `HomeController`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAppFormAppUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public HomeController(
        IAppFormAppUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

I get the error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I also put a break point in `RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)` method and it gets hit.

What i am missing, doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 + Ninject MVC 3 = No parameterless constructor defined for this object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311479/asp-net-mvc-4-ninject-mvc-3-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-ob)

Comment: Its such an annoying error. Basically though, it means Ninject wasn't registered properly and has not registered itself as the Controller Factory for MVC.

Comment: Did you register your `NinjectControllerFactory` with `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory` or register your `NinjectRependencyResolver` with `DependencyResolver.SetResolver`?

Comment: @Steven: No, that was the problem. Before, on MVC3, it was all working by default. Not you need to manually register the Controller Factory

Answer (score 0):

If you've registered your DependencyResolver.Current with Ninject, then, only one problem remains.

Ninject is getting an exception while is constructing your AppFormAppUnitOfWork to pass to your 
Constructor of your controller.

To find out what is that exception, you can write a few lines of code in some where such as begin request and try to resolve your object from DependencyResolver.Current.

Put that code in try catch, and then you will find the main source of a problem.

Good luck