# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Ninject + MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I have getting error that "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." in MVC 5 Application.

[image: Error]

Controller is:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private  IUserService userService;

        public HomeController(IUserService userService)
        {
            this.userService = userService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = userService.GetUser();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Ninject WebCOmmon cs class is :

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(QuestionWave.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(QuestionWave.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace QuestionWave.Web.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using QuestionWave.Data;
    using QuestionWave.Service;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<QuestionWaveDbEntities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        }        
    }
}
```

I have installed four Packages for Ninject

```
    <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

My DbContext class is:

```
public partial class QuestionWaveDbEntities : DbContext
{
    public QuestionWaveDbEntities()
        : base("name=QuestionWaveDbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I am using database first approach using EF. 
All constructors are public.

What going wrong with my code please suggest.

Comment: What does your UserService's constructor look like?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel User Service constructor is: 
`private readonly IRepository<User> userRepository;

      public UserService(IRepository<User> userRepository)
      {
          this.userRepository = userRepository;
      }`

Comment: And what does Repository<User> its constructor look like?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's generic repository :
`public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {      
        
        private readonly QuestionWaveDbEntities context;
        public Repository(QuestionWaveDbEntities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 5):

I used this way and is working. Create `Ninject` dependency resolver class:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;
    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
       kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
    }
}
```

And set your dependency resolver in `Global.asax Application_Start` method,

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
```

Comment: In this case, should I remove NinjectWebCommon.cs class under App_Start folder?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. All your bindings go in `AddBindings` method

Comment: Thanks, It works, but could you please elaborate that what Issues were in my code so that I could mark it accepted answer.

Comment: if I doesn't remove NinjectWebCommon.cs class under App_Start folder then we have two instance of StandardKernel so that's right ?

Comment: My solution is a work around, but found a similar problem here http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12311479/asp-net-mvc-4-ninject-mvc-3-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-ob. The answers there may help you.

Comment: Your solution works. I followed suggested link but get same error and it does not resolve my issue. I am still looking that why NinjectWebCommon.cs class is useless and causing issue? If I have NinjectWebCommon.cs class then it's `Start()` method calls and creates an instance of `StandardKernel()` and same instance we are also creating in  NinjectDependencyResolver.cs class so is it right way?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - since this worked for me... I think my issue was that the NinjectWebCommon was connecting to ApiController but not Controllers (MVC). Adding this made Controller work as well as ApiController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dropdownlist in View so you should change the attribute name from the list name which is being used to access the value.

example:
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.QualificationName, Model.QualificationList, "Select Qualification")

so these both name should be separated: "QualificationName, QualificationList"

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had circular dependencies in my project and Ninject could't resolve the dependencies. Once I deleted the circular dependencies my project started working again.